# Output Raw Data to Speakers

Tags: c++, windows, audio, wav

I'm a reasonably advanced C++ programmer, as a bit of background. At this point, I'm wanting to experiment a bit with sound. Rather than use a library to load and play files, I'm wanting to figure out how to actually do that myself, for the understanding. For this application, I would like to read in a .wav file (I already have that part down), then output that data to the speakers. How do I push a waveform or the data from the file to the speakers on my computer? I'm on Windows, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6543/Playing-WAV-files-using-the-Windows-Multi-Media-Li) about how to set up the audio device and how to stream data into the device for playback on Windows.  If using this library is too high-level for you and you'd like to go deeper and write your own decoding of WAV files and outputting that to a sound card, you have far more research to do than what's appropriate for an answer here.

Comment: Depending on how close to the metal he wants to get, he could also look into DirectSound or WASAPI, all documented on the interwebs.

Comment: As it turns out, after researching some, I've come across WaveOut, which appears to be pretty much exactly what I was looking. However, I'm having difficulty getting an example to play nicely. My end goal is to be able to do visuals or whatever based on the audio data, which is why I need to be able to access it in realtime.